# Why does the Android version of my MAUI app not have internet access?

Tags: c#, android, http, android-permissions, maui

In a .NET MAUI project, I have this line:

`var result = await client.GetStringAsync(https://localhost:7239/products/);`

When compiled to a Windows app, it works as intended; when compiled to an Android app, I get this error: "Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:7239".

Things I have already thought about checking:

- The emulated Android phone does have internet access. I tested its YouTube app.
- The AndoidManifest.xml file already contains `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`.
- Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Permissions does not have an internet access member I can request at runtime.

I would appreciate advice. I should mention that I am quite new to C#, and a complete noob with respect to MAUI and phone app development.

Comment: It does have internet access.  But `localhost` means **connect to myself**, which is the **android emulator**, not the host the emulator is running on.  So do NOT use `localhost`.  Use the IP or FQDN of the server.  There are numerous existing questions about networking and the Android emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Android developer docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking) you can use 10.0.2.2 when inside the emulator to reference the host machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle your problem according to your specific situation.

**First**, the `localhost` refers to the device on which the code is running.  As far as your question is concerned,  it is the android emulator.
In general,  we need to use the actual `IP` or the `FQDN` of the web url that we want to access,just as Jason mentioned.

**Second**，if you want to refer to the computer which is running the Android simulator, use the IP address `10.0.2.2`.(Remember this solution only works on emulators)

For more about this, you can check document [Set up Android Emulator networking](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking).

**Note:**

You can get the IP by command line:

```
  ipconfig /all
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also add UsesCleartextTraff = true as followed in the module Platforms/Android/Resources/MainApplication.cs

[Application(UsesCleartextTraffic =true)]